# Give a counterexample to show that $(AB)^{-1} \neq A^{-1}B^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

Give a counterexample to show that $(AB)^{-1}$ doesn't  equal $A^{-1}B^{-1}$

I'm not sure how to approach this, so I just used the idea that the matrix multiplication is not commutative. so it goes:

AB doesn't equal BA

now I just take the inverse of both sides if they are invertible (lets say they are)

so I get

$B^{-1}A^{-1}$ doesn't equal $A^{-1}B^{-1}$

meaning that the above is true.

I'm not good at doing proofs and as such my logic here is probably wrong so please someone verify if this is a method I could use to prove such.

Comment: What you're missing right now is an explicit counterexample. Following your logic above, that just means you need to give a pair of matrices which don't commute.

Comment: Well it *could be* that all invertible matrices are commutative.  (Which is not true.) But one counterexample would be $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: To make the same point in another way - it is *not true* that $AB\ne BA$ for all $A,B$, but there do exist some $A,B$ for which $AB\ne BA$ - so find a pair (that are also invertible), and you have an explicit counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Find any two invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ that do not commute i.e. $AB \neq BA$. Taking inverse on both sides, $(AB)^{-1}\neq (BA)^{-1}$

Comment: so I should use real numbers to prove this correct?

Comment: yes. Finding 2x2 matrices would be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

What you need now is an example of two invertible matrices that commute.  How about
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$